# MVC 5 Routing and Optional Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the following controller and route definition

```c#
[System.Web.Mvc.Route("users/{firstName?}/{lastName?}/{emailAddress?}/{pageSize:int=10}/{pageNumber:int=1}", Name = RouteNames.User_Listing)]
public ActionResult Index(string firstName = null, string lastName = null, string emailAddress = null, int pageNumber = 1, int pageSize = 10)
```

What I want is for any of these to be undefined or defined and so all these would be valid

```
users/first/last/email
users/last/email/30/2
users/last/1
users
```

Problem is, how does MVC know which of the parameters has been specified?  It doesn't!

When I have this link

```
@Html.RouteLink("Maintain Users", RouteNames.User_Listing)
```

it doesn't navigate to this action method.  What do I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right, MVC won't know which one (other than the left-most parameter is the "most required". That is to say, you can't specify an `{email}` without first specifying `{firstName?}/{lastName?}/`.

However, you can bind it to match different formats but just keep in mind that the **first match** MVC finds it's going to run with (and if that means placing the `emailAddress` in the `firstName` field, it will. (Though you can also add an email constraint to that parameters to it matches `*@*.*` (or some facsimile) to avoid that).

I would either re-evaluate how you want the routes, or consider putting the basic information in to the url (paging), and keep the optional parameters as query string values. e.g.

```
users/30/2?firstName=___&lastName=___
users/30/2?emailAddress=___&lastName=___
users/30/2?firstName=___&emailAddress=____&lastName=___
```

Answer (score 7):

You just need to specify multiple attributes for this action:

```
[Route("users/{firstName?}")]
[Route("users/{firstName}/{lastName?}")]
[Route("users/{firstName}/{lastName}/{emailAddress?}")]
...
```

Comment: This actually doesn't do anything to address the OP's question because he wants to be able to specify ".../users/Smith" and have the routing figure out that it needs to set "firstName" equal to null and set "lastName" equal to "Smith".  As Brad pointed out in his answer, you cannot do that with routing.

Comment: may be you're right - I reread the question multiple times, it's not very clear

Answer (score 3):

Just add *?* to passing parameter

```
[Route("~/Splash/MerchantSetup/{id?}")]
public ActionResult MerchantSetup(int? id)
        {
             // your code
        }
```